# Can unique Tumblr Twitter Tags values in the HEAD be called?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, tumblr

Tumblr automatically loads these unique Vimeo content values for Twitter cards in every post.

```
<!-- TWITTER TAGS -->
...
<meta name="twitter:image"
content="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/123/123/460802785_200.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:player"
content="https://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=123456789&amp;amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;amp;fullscreen=1&amp;amp;show_title=1&amp;amp;show_byline=0&amp;amp;show_portrait=0&amp;amp;color=00ADEF" />
...
```

Since I have more than a lot of Vimeo videos embeded to Tumblr posts, can I pre-load these Twitter Card content values for Open Graph Video in the HEAD theme template also? For example:

```
meta property="og:video" content="{Load Vimeo Flash Video URL}"
```